# Why does the TextEditor view display sharp edges on the inside of my border?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a TextEditor that takes input in a neat fashion, but get a sharp edge on the inside of the TextEditor.

```
import SwiftUI

struct InitialRewardSet: View {
    @State var rewardDesc = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ZStack{
                VStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Text("What will you treat yourself to")
                        .bold()
                        
                    Text("after you achieve the goal you set?")
                        .bold()
                        
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                }
                VStack{
                    TextEditor(text: $rewardDesc)
                        .border(Color.blue, width: 5)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 100)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous))
                }
            }
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: {NiceScreen()}, label: {Text("Next")})
            }
        }
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    InitialRewardSet()
}
```

[This is the preview I am getting with the given code. Trying to not use any depreciated code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYWQL.png)

I tried using .clipShape and .border while resizing the TextEditor, but get an unpleasant sharp inside edge on the border. I was expecting it to just smoothly adapt to the changes I made.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```swift
TextEditor(text: $rewardDesc)
    .frame(width: 250, height: 100)
    .cornerRadius(20) // <- Rounded background
    .overlay(content: { // <- Rounded border the entire content
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
            .strokeBorder(.blue, lineWidth: 5)
    })
```

Output

[image]